# Pass dbf data to sentence and save as text file using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dbf

I have a script which exports some results to a dbf file (dbf is my only export option for the software I am using). I would like to use these results (number of rows will vary) to output a sentence containing the results to a file.

For example

Cars.dbf

```
Toyota
Mazda
Kia
Volkswagon
```

I want to output the following sentence:

Within this neighborhood there is a Toyota, Mazda, Kia, and Volkswagon parked on the street.

If the results are two I do not want commas:

Cars.dbf

```
Toyota
Mazda
```

Within this neighborhood there is a Toyota and Mazda parked on the street.

Cars.dbf

```
empty
```

There are no cars parked on the street within this neighborhood.

I know how to do if else statements, but am unsure how to pass the dbf records as variables in a sentence. Ideas anyone?

Using python 2.7.

A thousand thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [my dbf package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf):

```
import dbf
table = dbf.Table('Cars', default_data_types={'C':dbf.Char})  # don't want extra spaces
cars = []
table.open()
for record in table:
    cars.append(record[0])   # or cars.append(record.make) if 'make' is the field name

if len(cars) == 1 and cars[0] == 'empty'):
    # print no cars sentence
elif len(cars) == 1:
    # print one car sentence
elif len(cars) == 2:
    # print two car sentence
else:
    # print many car sentence
```

After the `for record in table` loop all the names are in the `cars` list.  At that point it is simple string substitution:

```
# many car case
first = "Within this neighborhood there is a "
last = " parked on the street."
middle = ('%s, ' * (len(cars)-1) + 'and a %s') % tuple(cars)
print first + middle + last+
```

The `middle =` line is getting a little fancy with string substitution.  Each `%s` will be replaced by an entry from `cars`, and if you have to have the same number of items in `cars` as you have `%s`'s.  And of course you want an 'and' just before the last item.  So if you have four cars:

```
cars = ['Mazda', 'Ford', 'Dodge', 'Yugo']
```

then

```
len(cars) - 1 == 3
```

so

```
'%s, ' * (len(cars)-1) == '%s, %s, %s, '
```

and then we add the last part

```
'%s, ' * (len(cars)-1) + 'and a %s' == '%s, %s, %s, and a %s'
```

finally, the `%` string substitute function sees

```
'%s, %s, %s, and a %s' % tuple(cars)
```

which would give us

```
 'Mazda, Ford, Dodge, and a Yugo'
```

Note: we had to say `tuple(cars)` because `cars` was a `list` and `%` needs either a single item or a tuple of items.

Comment: This looks great but of course I missed one detail. The output needs to be a text file. How would I do this?

Comment: @user12059: Check out [the `open` docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open): basically something like `answer = open('textfile.txt','w'); answer.write(sentence)`

Comment: Can you describe in detail what this line is doing:  middle = ('%s, ' * (len(cars)-1) + 'and a %s') % tuple(cars)